# Serialization - What is the advantage of using ObjectStreamField [] serialPersistentFields?

Tags: java, serialization

For class that implements `Serializable` interface there are 2 ways to define what specific fields get streamed during the serialization:

1. By default all non-static, non-transient fields that implement `Serializable` are preserved.
2. By definning `ObjectStreamField [] serialPersistentFields` and explicitly declaring the specific fields saved.

I wonder, what is the advantage of the second method except for the ability to define specific fields order?

Comment: Ah I didn't see that the answer was already accepted.  That answer is correct but I don't think it answers your question "why".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'advantage' is that it does what it says in the Javadoc: defines which fields are serialized. Without it, all non-transient non-static fields are serialized. Your choice.

Comment: So why not just make them 'transient'?

Comment: @aviad because it might break something else, or you might want to make use of the `unshared` feature, ...

Comment: Break what? readUnshared() only invalidates the strream handle the object came from - please elaborate ( I fail to recognize the correlation)

Comment: @aviad (a) Break anything else that relies on the field being non-transient, such as some possible XML serializer, and (b) you need to look up `writeUnshared()`: this is an effect you cannot get by default.

Comment: a) got your point.b) writeUnshared() allows a single object to be defined multiple times in a stream. I still do not understand how is this feature connected to the 2nd method and what would not work if I used the 'transient' to filter the fields streamed

Comment: @aviad (a) an ObjectStreamField can have an 'unshared' parameter (b) it isn't hard to imagine alternate serializers such as the XML serializers I mentioned which might or might not take notice of the 'transient' field ... so you would get different behaviours. `java.beans.XMLEncoder` is one example.

Answer (score 3):

The advantage is you can conditionally populate ObjectStreamField at runtime albeit only once per JVM lifecycle to determine which fields should be serialized.

```
private static final ObjectStreamField [] osf;
static {
    //code to init osf
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Luckily, I'm actually writing this up right now....  Besides the advantages mentioned (and I don't know much about unshared), writing your own output format seems to have the following advantages:

- Allows conditional output (different uses for serialization, such as persistence and copying, can serialize different parts of the object).
- Should be faster, use less memory, and in some cases use less disk than the default mechanism (this is from Bloch's *Effective Java 2*).
- Allows you to rename variables in a serialized class while maintaining backwards-compatibility.
- Allows you to access data from deleted fields in a new version (in other words, change the internal representation of your data while maintaining backwards-compatibility).

I've seen the documentation you're quoting, and mentioning just those 2 options is a bit misleading and leaves quite a bit out:  you can customize your serialization format in 2 ways, by using the ObjectOutput/InputStream interface to write and read fields in a particular order (described in Bloch), and using the PutField and GetField classes to write and read fields by name.  You can use serialPersistentFields as your quote mentions to extend this second method, but it's not required unless you need to read or write data with a name which is not a member variable name.

There's a 3rd way to control format as well, using the Externizable interface, though I haven't explored that much.  And some of the advantages can also be gotten through Serialization Proxies (see Bloch).

Anyone feel free to correct me on details if I missed anything.

Answer (score 0):

In `serialPersistentFields` you can specify fields that are not necessarily present in the class anymore.

See for example the jdk class `java.math.BigInteger`, where several fields are read and written which don't exist anymore in the class. These obsolete fields are still read and written for compatibility with older versions. The reading and writing of these fields is handled by the `readObject()` and `writeObject()` methods.

See also
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#6250